# QtCore/QTextCodec not found in Qt 6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

After upgrading to Qt 6.0, the compiler told me

```
qzxing/src/QZXing.cpp:16: error: 'QtCore/QTextCodec' file not found
qzxing/src/QZXing.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'QtCore/QTextCodec' file not found
#include <QtCore/QTextCodec>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qzxing/src/QZXing.cpp:16:10: note: did not find header 'QTextCodec' in framework 'QtCore' (loaded from '/Applications/Qt/6.0.0/clang_64/lib')
```

According to [Qt's documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/internationalization.html), it can be imported by adding `QT += core5compat`.
However, the compiler told me that "Unknown module(s) in QT: core5compat".

How to solve this problem?

Comment: For new users of Qt 6, you can use [QStringConverter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html) and its derived classes: [QStringDecoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringdecoder.html) & [QStringEncoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringencoder.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have installed "Qt 5 Compatibility Module".
2. Add `QT += core5compat` in .pro file.
3. Replace `#include <QtCore/QTextCodec>` to `#include <QTextCodec>`

[image: Qt Installer]

Comment: As the QTextCodec now lives in the compatibility library, is there a replacement class?

Comment: @albert QStringConverter is QTextCodec's replacement class.

Answer (score 7):

The QTextCodec class was moved to the core5compat submodule so it is not enough to add that in the .pro, but you must correct the import to:

```cpp
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    #include <QtCore/QTextCodec>
#else
    #include <QtCore5Compat/QTextCodec>
#endif
```

Or simply

```
#include <QTextCodec>
```

On the other hand, you must install this module since it does not come by default and for this you must use *Maintenance Tool*.

Comment: As the QTextCodec now lives in the compatibility library, is there a replacement class?

Comment: @albert QStringConverter is QTextCodec's replacement class.

Answer (score 2):

add `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION,5): QT += core5compat`  in .pro file

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide a comprehensive answer.